# Image Crop Not Working

Tags: functions, images

I am building a custom WordPress theme.

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to have an area for the user to upload custom images.

This is what I have in my functions.php file. My images aren't taking up the full designated space, instead they are being cropped by their ratio.

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
    add_image_size( 'blog', 810, 400, true );
    add_image_size( 'home-right-column-block', 305, 300, true); 
  }
  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );
```

Each time I test something, I ensure I upload a fresh new image and the image I upload is way larger than the dimensions I've specified so it should work.

Comment: Other image sizes do exist on your server, you should be calling them instead of the original http://www.aubsandmugg.com/clients/019-mp-website/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ (or fix your CSS maybe)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to pass the image in as an ID rather than a URL.

```
<?php
    $image_id = get_field('content_image_1');
    $image_size = 'home-left-column-block';
    $image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, $image_size);
    $image_url = $image_array[0];
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo the_field('content_block_title_1'); ?>" height="420" width="630">
```